# Highcharts no drilldown on bar / column click

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

I have the following use case: On a page there is a Highcharts column with drilldown [as in this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown).
When the labels below the bars are clicked, I would like to drilldown, as default. However, when the bar / column itself is clicked, I do not want to drilldown but rather get information on the clicked bar (e. g. the name of the category). How is this possible?

What I've tried so far is to evaluate the click event with jQuery and then stop drilling down by using "return false;". The problem with that is that I have seen no way to retrieve the column data as the JavaScript object itself is not accessible.
What I did then is to use the "drilldown" event. I can now easily access the objects data / properties but have have two difficulties:

1. How to identify whether a bar or the label below the bar was clicked?
2. How can I prevent the drilldown in case a bar was clicked?

Thank you in advance for hints and tips!

Andy

Comment: you can have a click event for the bar try to prevent the default click behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap `doDrilldown` method, and there decide what should happen and when, snippet:

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'doDrilldown', function (p, hold, x) {
    var UNDEFINED;
    if (x !== UNDEFINED) {
        p.call(this, hold, x); // x is defined when clicked on a category
    } else {
        myFun(this); // call your method after click on a bar
    }
  });
})(Highcharts)
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L51c8fa4/

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly! Just one question: Is this documented in the Highcharts documentation or how does one come up with such a solution?

Comment: I work for Highcharts ;) We monitor stackoverflow as well as our forum or emails. In general [extending Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) is documented. But to find proper method to wrap, you need to dig into the source code.